# Will factory resetting my device remove the Android upgrade?

Tags: updates, factory-reset

I have upgraded my phone to Android 2.1. I need to reset my phone but I don't want to lose the upgrade. Is it possible to do this? How?

Answer (score 10):

Don't worry, a factory reset will not change the version of the OS installed. You'll have the same OS version after the reset. However, as I'm sure you are aware, you will lose all your data.