# Upgraded my phone from 1.6 to 2.2 Android version, if I restore "Factory Settings", which version it will be?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, updates, factory-reset, 1.6-donut

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will factory resetting my device remove the Android upgrade?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12626/will-factory-resetting-my-device-remove-the-android-upgrade)

I upgraded my Galaxy 551 from 1.6 to 2.2 Android version some time ago with Samsung Kies, now I want to make a factory reset due to reset all of my settings and give the phone to my mother.

I'm wondering about wich version the factory reset will bring to me. It is the factory version (1.6) or the upgraded version (2.1)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Factory Reset doesn't take your device back to factory condition. It just clears all data, settings, etc.

So your phone will not go back to older Android version. It will be on the upgraded Android version (or any ROM that you have installed) with all data cleared!

Watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hxDWfdXVa1c) for more help. At [5:30](http://youtu.be/hxDWfdXVa1c?t=5m30s) the guy answers exactly what you are asking.

Comment: On the funny side, I just happened hover over the "factory-reset" tag from the question, it says: "A factory reset results in a full reset of an Android device to the original settings of the currently-installed ROM." That pretty much answers the question I guess! :D