# Nexus 4 factory reset

Tags: updates, 4.2-jelly-bean, factory-reset, nexus-4, 4.3-jelly-bean

My nexus 4 originally came with android 4.2 JB. Since then I have gotten the 4.3 update. If i perform a factory reset sometime in the future will it go back to 4.2 or will the update be still in place. Also is there anyway to downgrade the os?

Comment: [Will factory resetting my device remove the Android upgrade?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12626/will-factory-resetting-my-device-remove-the-android-upgrade) covers your first question (the answer is no, it won't downgrade).

Comment: Is there a way to rollback or does the upgrade overwrite the previous os?

Comment: The only way you can downgrade is rooting it and then reinstalling the stock ROM and then unrooting. Is there a reason why you want to roll back to 4.2?

Comment: There is no specific reason...the only thing I was thinking is even though the current updates add performance boost, i feel that in the future some updates may begin to slow the device down as the software will be built for newer hardware. Just curiosity i guess

Comment: Your device will only get updated so many times. My Droid 3 is still running Froyo because the Google gurus decided it was too old for the next generation of Android. Trust me, when your device receives an update, it has been thoroughly tested to make sure it is bug free and is at it's maximum performance. When your device gets too old, you will stop getting updates.