# after factory reset can nexus get lollipop through ota?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I use nexus 4 which got updated to lollipop on 27th Nov via ota . the thing is the phone got reset by mistake n it again came back to jellybean will it get the update again through ota ?? Or is there any other way? I don't knowto install it manually..

Comment: A factory reset [doesn't downgrade Android](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/12626/981). What, precisely, happened that caused your device to downgrade?

Comment: The play services stopped and the pop up started appearing now n then . I took it to the service center. The guy over there jus did the factory reset n gave the phone back. He didn't even inform me that he was gonna do that... So that's what happened n the phone came back to its original that's jelly bean, now what I wanted to know is will it recieve any update through ota? Or m I supposed to install it manually..

Answer (score 0):

If your ***Current Rom*** `Country (Or region)` have Lollipop Update,

yes you can.

Else (Install manually) :

- **For find Frimware :**

[Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

Or download `factory image` : ([developers.google](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images))

- **How to Install :**

  ( [From android.stackexchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/50035/82964) )

[How to install Android 5.0 Lollipop on a Nexus 4](http://www.androidpit.com/how-to-install-android-5-0-lollipop-on-a-nexus-4)

[How to manually install Android Lollipop on a Nexus device](http://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-manually-install-android-lollipop-nexus-device-windows-linux-563546/)